# Is it possible to create a Whatsapp bot to take orders from customers?

Tags: chat, chatbot, whatsapp

We decided to use a Whatsapp bot instead of developing separate mobile applications for our prepared foods company. General Use-Case will be like these,

#### The Whatsapp bot shows a welcome message and provides a command list like

**Please select one of the options below to continue...**

1 - to get more information about working hours.

2 - to display the food menu

3 - to make an order

after selecting one of them, the bot will provide another menu to customers.
In addition to this, order conversation should be like these

**Customer: 3**

Bot: Which menu do you want to order?

**Customer: 12**

Bot: how many would you like from this menu?

**Customer: 2**

Bot: Do you want to add another menu to your cart?

**Customer: Yes**

Bot: Which menu do you want to order?

**Customer: 8**

Bot: how many would you like from this menu?

**Customer: 1**

Bot: Do you want to add another menu to your cart?

**Customer: No**

and etc.

### The question is that is it possible to create a Whatsapp bot to take orders from customers by using chain conversations like above?

Comment: I see you've added the [tag:botframework] tag. Are you using the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Comment: sorry, I added unconsciously. I didn't know it is a special phrase for Microsoft Bot Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. I would suggest using Python in order to take py-requests from WhatsApp and taking input from users using the input function in python:

```
val = input("Your input here")
```

You could then use this input to print the messages that you provided and use the user input by storing it for later use in this program, in this case adding more items to your cart. However, next time, try to add some code you have tried before asking the question so people can find problems in it and help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I wondered another thing about it too, How can I ensure that the bot distinguishing answers whether is pizza quantity or drinks quantity?  After all, answers may consist of the same numbers or letters. Could I explain?

Comment: Please elaborate more, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you can use an [open source bot framework like Botonic](https://botonic.io). It's based on Javascrip and React, pretty straightforward to create a guided dialog like the one you describe. Whatsapp API is still in private beta, but you can deploy your bot to a platform like [Hubtype](https://hubtype.com) and connect it to Whatsapp.

Comment: Thank you too, Could you answer the question in the comment above?

Comment: @p_escobr have a look at botonic tutorials or examples like this: https://github.com/hubtype/botonic-examples/tree/master/telco-offers